# How to migrate from background page context design to service worker's passing messages between other contexts design?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker

I'm very green when it comes to working with service workers and I'm trying to understand how to migrate from functions such as `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` which most of the extensions I'm working with use, to a design that passes messages between contexts and the service worker [according to Google's checklist](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration-checklist/); but there isn't much of an example to go off of.

Here is a small example of the current design I have. I have a main js page that imports scripts for methods which acts as a global scope when called by `getBackgroundPage()` on other files. This file also does some other things, but I'm keeping it brief.

Main.js

```
importScripts("js/store.js", "js/config.js", "js/utility.js", "js/log.js", "js/search.js")

    var _Store = _Store || new Store();
    var _Config = _Config || new Config(_Store);

    let Util = new Utility(_Config, _Store);
```

I have another file that utilizes `Main.js` methods, and attempts to build the url on each new tab opening. In this example, its the _Config:

URLBuild.js

```
let Background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    let NTURL = '';
    if (Background) {
        if (Background._Config) {
            NTURL = Background._Config.getNTURL();
        }
     }

     if (typeof (NTURL) !== 'undefined' && NTURL !== '' && NTURL !== null) {
        NTLocation(chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()._Config.getNTURL());
     }

function NTLocation(url) {
        if (typeof (url) !== 'undefined' && url !== '' && url.indexOf('https:') > -1) {
            chrome.tabs.create({ "url": url + "&iid=myid_" + chrome.runtime.getManifest().version + "&" });
        } else {
            chrome.tabs.create({ "url": FallBackMethod() });
        }
    }
```

From my understanding, I'm trying to simulate how this is done via service workers by passing messages but I feel that this might be the wrong direction I'm taking from my lack of understanding. Here's my attempt at that:

Main.js

```
//"server"
    addEventListener('message', event => {
        console.log(`The client sent me a message: ${event.data}`)
        event.source.postMessage(_Config);
    })
```

URLBuild.js

```
// "client"
let myConfig;
    if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-wrapper.js');

        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
            registration.active.postMessage("Ask for Config Object");
        });

        navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {
            myConfig = event.data;
        });


    }
```

If this is the incorrect way of approaching things, what does the design of passing messages between other contexts and the service worker look like?

Comment: Forget all about service workers you know as those things are unused by extensions and remove all that code with addEventListener and navigator. The messaging API you need is `chrome.runtime`, see the [examples in the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). Alternatively, simply include the js files in your page and it'll work orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: @wOxxOm This was definitely the direction I needed to head in, thank you! Feel free to put down your answer and I'll mark it